# Stop certain components from being rerendered when the prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I tried to make a calculator work in React Native. What I quickly realized there was a noticeable delay from button press to the value being displayed. On every inputted value the state changes, causing a re-render of the whole component. So far this is expected, but I don't want to have to re-render every single button in the Calculator component. If I press on one button I don't feel like all the other buttons should also have to re-render. since this doubles the rendering time of the calculator, causing a noticeable delay from button press to the number being displayed. How can I fix this?

In profiler it says that the Buttons re-render because the onPress changed. This would be the handleSymbolPress. I tried to use useCallback on it, but it didn't work, I assume it was because calculation is changed every time the function is called. The only way I could prohibit the re-render of these buttons was to use useCallback with an empty dependency on the individual buttons themselves. This didn't either work, the inputted values just kept overriding the old inputted value. I assume this is because the useCallback hasn't access to the updated calculation state. Adding calculation as a dependency to that useCallback would cause them all to re-render just as I don't want them to do.

So, is there a way to make this work, to only re-render the Button that is actually being used? How should I go about this?

I tried looking at examples at GitHub but several of those I checked were as slow as the one I have.

I appreciate any help!

```
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { evaluate } from 'mathjs';

import { defaultStyles } from '../config/styles';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

const { width: deviceWidth, height: deviceHeight } = Dimensions.get('window');

function Calculator({}) {
console.log('MainCalculator rendered');

const [calculation, setCalculation] = useState('0');

const handleSymbolPress = useCallback(
    (symbol) => {
        console.log('calculation:', calculation, symbol);
        switch (symbol) {
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
                if (
                    calculation.endsWith('+') ||
                    calculation.endsWith('-') ||
                    calculation.endsWith('*') ||
                    calculation.endsWith('/')
                ) {
                    setCalculation(calculation.slice(0, -1) + symbol);
                } else {
                    setCalculation(calculation + symbol);
                }
                break;
            case '.':
                if (!calculation.includes('.')) {
                    setCalculation(calculation + symbol);
                }
                break;
            case 'C':
                setCalculation('0');
                break;
            case '=':
                try {
                    const result = evaluate(calculation);
                    setCalculation(String(result));
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                break;
            default:
                if (calculation === '0') {
                    setCalculation(symbol);
                } else {
                    setCalculation(calculation + symbol);
                }
                break;
        }
    },
    [calculation]
);

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.calculationContainer}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.appMainCalculation}
                value={calculation}
                onChangeText={setCalculation}
                showSoftInputOnFocus={false}
                caretHidden={false}
            />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.extraPadButton}>
            <Button title='C' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('C')} />
            <Button title='(' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('(')} />
            <Button title=')' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress(')')} />
            <Button title='/' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('/')} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.padButtonsContainer}>
            <View style={styles.padButtonRow}>
                <Button title='7' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('7')} />
                <Button
                    title='8'
                    onPress={useCallback(
                        () => handleSymbolPress('8'),
                        [calculation]
                    )}
                />
                <Button title='9' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('9')} />
                <Button title='*' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('*')} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.padButtonRow}>
                <Button title='4' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('4')} />
                <Button title='5' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('5')} />
                <Button
                    title='6'
                    onPress={useCallback(() => handleSymbolPress('6'))}
                />
                <Button title='-' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('-')} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.padButtonRow}>
                <Button title='1' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('1')} />
                <Button title='2' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('2')} />
                <Button title='3' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('3')} />
                <Button title='+' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('+')} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.padButtonRow}>
                <Button title='0' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('0')} />
                <Button title='.' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('.')} />
                <Button title='=' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('=')} />
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
);
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    // backgroundColor: defaultStyles.colors.white,
    paddingBottom: deviceHeight * 0.05,
},
calculationContainer: {
    width: deviceWidth * 0.9,
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    marginBottom: deviceHeight * 0.02,
},
appMainCalculation: {
    textAlign: 'right',
    fontSize: deviceHeight * 0.07,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    width: '100%',
},
appMainCalculationText: {
    color: defaultStyles.colors.dark,
},
extraPadButton: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginBottom: deviceHeight * 0.02,
    width: deviceWidth * 0.9,
},
padButtonsContainer: {
    width: deviceWidth * 0.9,
},
padButtonRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginBottom: deviceHeight * 0.02,
},
});

export default Calculator;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to keep the callback from being recreated is to pass in `calculation` at the point of calling the function instead of making it a dependency of the useCallback.

```js
const handleSymbolPress = useCallback(
  (symbol, calc) => {
    switch (symbol) {
      case '+':
      case '-':
      case '*':
      case '/':
        if (calc.endsWith('+') {
        ... // function body
  }, []); // empty dependency array

  //...

  return (
    // ...
    <Button title='C' onPress={() => handleSymbolPress('C', calculation)} />
    // etc
```

However, this won't stop the Button components from being recomputed.  If you were to add console logs to the Button component body, they would still fire on every state change - React needs to compute their result to compare them to the existing DOM.  This doesn't mean that they are re-rendered; if the result is the same, React won't render them again.

I've tried running your code (using console.log instead of evaluate), and I'm not seeing any performance hit.  You will see some performance decrease from being in debug mode and running the profiler.

Comment: I did pass the calc as a parameter, but it didn't change the rerendering. I could only stop the buttons from rerender when a useCallb with an empty dependency, was added to the onPress. Here I also passed the calc as a parameter, but it still used the old calculation state, since it hadn't been updated. I wonder how I can pass the updated value only when pressing the button, so it won't rerender every time the state changes unless the button was pressed, but still getting the most recent value. I noticed was a delay from pressing a button to seeing it on the screen, maybe caused by debug mode.